# C# XML file display information of login user

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio

I am learning C# and I am working on a problem. I created XML files with Different users' information. I have a problem to display a particular user information when his login. I would like to display the information of the person who used his username and password.

Because right now even if the first user login I see info of the second.

This is my code to display info, but it does not work properly

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("UserInfo.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/UsersInfo/UserInfo");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{       
    FirstName.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText;
    LastName.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText;
    DateOfBirth.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("DateOfBirth").InnerText;
    Nationality.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("Nationality").InnerText;
    Passport.Text=node.SelectSingleNode("Passport").InnerText;
    Address.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("Address").InnerText;
    Phone.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("phone").InnerText;
```

Comment: Mary, the code you've provided isn't enough to define what doesn't work. Show the code with logging in and displaying the current user on the form

Comment: Can you show your XML template? How many user's info do u have in that file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as an example. This is how i pull the weather. Its the same thing as what your trying to do but using a different method. The code I am showing is an example

```
 private void GetWeather()
    {
        string query = string.Format("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12773086");
        XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
        wData.Load(query);

        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");

        XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");
        XmlNodeList nodes = wData.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item/yweather.forecast", manager);

        Temperature = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["temp"].Value;

        Condition = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;

        Humidity = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:atmosphere", manager).Attributes["humidity"].Value;

        Visibility = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:atmosphere", manager).Attributes["visibility"].Value;

        Pressure = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:atmosphere", manager).Attributes["pressure"].Value;

        Rising = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:atmosphere", manager).Attributes["rising"].Value;

        Town = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:location", manager).Attributes["city"].Value;

        State = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:location", manager).Attributes["region"].Value;

        Windspeed = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:wind", manager).Attributes["speed"].Value;

        Windchill = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:wind", manager).Attributes["chill"].Value;

        TFCond = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;

        TFHigh = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["high"].Value;

        TFLow = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["low"].Value;

        Distance = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:units", manager).Attributes["distance"].Value;

        Sunrise = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:astronomy", manager).Attributes["sunrise"].Value;

        Sunset = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:astronomy", manager).Attributes["sunset"].Value;

        Speed = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:units", manager).Attributes["speed"].Value;

        BPressure = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:units", manager).Attributes["pressure"].Value;

        Degrees = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:units", manager).Attributes["temperature"].Value;

        Country = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:location", manager).Attributes["country"].Value;
    }
```

Then look at the word Temperature. In order to use this you would add

```
string Temperature;
```

then you could use it as like shown below

```
 case "whats it like outside":
                      GetWeather();
                      Alexis.SpeakAsync("Currently it is, " + Condition + "with a high of " + Temperature + Degrees + ", there is a humidity of " + Humidity + "percent, and a windspeed of " + Windspeed + Speed);
                      break;
```

this is in my app i use everyday. SO this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

From the little I can see of your code it would seem like you are looping through each user in the collection rather than selecting a specific user. You can use linq to form a query to select specific elements based on the values contained in the elements, something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xdoc =
            XDocument.Load(
                @"~\Examples\user.xml");

        var users = xdoc.Descendants("userInfo");

        // get the specific user
        var user = users.Where(x => x.Element("Passport").Value == "1");

        // get the value from each child element in the selected user 
        foreach(var element in user.Elements())
            {
            Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that the passport field is a unique identifier for the purposes of the linq query and as you can see, this is a very brief example.

The xml I used:

```
<UsersInfo>
    <userInfo>
        <FirstName>First</FirstName>
        <LastName>Last</LastName>
        <Passport>1</Passport>
    </userInfo>
    <userInfo>
        <FirstName>Second</FirstName>
        <LastName>Last</LastName>
        <Passport>2</Passport>
    </userInfo>
</UsersInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to match the username and password from the UserInfo nodes. So, just put an if construct in there (making the assumption that the username and password are stored in the XML)...

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("UserInfo.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/UsersInfo/UserInfo");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    if (node.SelectSingleNode("Username").InnerText == username &&
            node.SelectSingleNode("Password").InnertText == password)
    {
        FirstName.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText;
        LastName.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText;
        DateOfBirth.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("DateOfBirth").InnerText;
        Nationality.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("Nationality").InnerText;
        Passport.Text=node.SelectSingleNode("Passport").InnerText;
        Address.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("Address").InnerText;
        Phone.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("phone").InnerText;
    }
}
```

Then you will be matching only the user whose username and password match that entered (username/password variables).

And you should also consider hashing the password rather than storing it in plain text, if you haven't done so yet.